# Applying machine learning algorithms on Google's Quickdraw dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to apply machine learning algorithms available in python's scikit-learn package to predict doodle names from set of doodle images.

Since I'm a complete beginner in machine learning and I have no knowledge about how neural network work yet. I wanted to try with scikit-learn's algorithms.

I've downloaded doodles ( of cats and guitars ) with the help of api named [quickdraw](https://quickdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

Then I load the images with the following code

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import random

#To hold image arrays
images = []

#0-cat, 1-guitar
target = []

#5000 images of cats and guitar each
for i in range(5000):

   #cat images are named like cat0.png, cat1.png ...
   img = Image.open('data/cats/cat'+str(i)+'.png')
   img = np.array(img)
   img = img.flatten()
   images.append(img)
   target.append(0)

   #guitar images are named like guitar0.png, guitar1.png ...
   img = Image.open('data/guitars/guitar'+str(i)+'.png')
   img = np.array(img)
   img = img.flatten()
   images.append(img)
   target.append(1)

random.shuffle(images)
random.shuffle(target)
```

Then I applied the algorithm : -

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(images,target,test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
GB = GaussianNB()
GB.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(GB.score(X_test,y_test))
```

Upon running the above code (with other algorithms like SVM,MLP too), My system just freezes. I've do a force shutdown to get back. I'm not sure why is this happening.

I have tried lowering the number of images to load by changing

```
for i in range(5000):
```

to

```
for i in range(1000):
```

But I only get accuracy around 50%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if I may say so:

> Since I'm a complete beginner in machine learning and I have no knowledge about >how neural network work yet. I wanted to try with scikit-learn's algorithms.

This is not a good way to approach ML in general, I strongly suggest you start studying the basics at least, otherwise you won't be able to tell what's going on at all (it's not something you can figure out by trying it).

Back to your problem, applying Naive Bayes methods to raw images it's not a good strategy: the problem is that each pixel of your image is a *feature* and with images you can get a very high number of dimensions easily (also assuming each pixel is independant of its neighbors it's not what you want).
NB is commonly used with documents and looking at this example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Document_classification) might help you understand a bit more the algorithm.

In short, NB boils down to computing joint conditional probabilities, which boils down to counting co-occurences of *features* (*words* in wikipedia's example) being co-occurences of *pixels* in your case, which in turn boils down to computing a huge matrix of occurences that you need to formulate your NB model.

Now, if your matrix is made of all the *words* in a set of documents, this can get pretty expensive in both time and space (O(n^2)/2), with n being the number of *features*; instead, imagine the matrix being composed of ALL the pixels in your training set, as you're doing in your example... this explodes really fast.

That's why cutting your dataset to 1000 images allows your PC to not run out of memory.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. so scikit learn algorithms are not good for image data? or just naive bayes.

Comment: No I would't go as far as saying that the scikit tools are not suitable for images, but some of them surely requires some sort of "pre-processing" so that it is feasible; you should try NB with docs if you want to try it out.

Comment: Do you mind accepting the answer if you find it good for your question?